# FluentNHibernate 1.1 / Castle 1.1 dependency

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, castle-windsor

I would like to upgrade my FluentNHibernate to version 1.1, but I found out it uses Castle.Core 1.1.

I use Castle.Windsor 1.2 in my app which works with Castle.Core 1.2.

I now need to find a version of Castle.Windsor that uses this earlier version of Castle.Core, but I can't find it anywhere.

What do you recommend I should do?

- Wait for a version of FluentNHibernate that uses the latest Castle.Core?
- OR build FluentNHibernate 1.1 from source using the latest Castle.Core?
- OR downgrade my Castle.Windsor version?

Comment: Have you tried to use assembly binding redirection (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2fc472t2(VS.71).aspx) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to build FluentNHibernate against the lastest version of Castle, add this to your app.config/web.config file :

```
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Castle.DynamicProxy2" publicKeyToken="407dd0808d44fbdc" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="2.1.0.0" newVersion="2.2.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Castle.Core" publicKeyToken="407dd0808d44fbdc" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.2.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 3):

Only NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.dll and Castle.DynamicProxy2.dll depend on Castle.Core.dll.

You can get them compiled against Castle.Core.dll 1.2 from the [Castle ActiveRecord 2.1.1 release](http://sourceforge.net/projects/castleproject/files/ActiveRecord/2.1/AR%202.1.1.zip/download).

Comment: I had the versioning problem in a slightly unrelated case, but swapping the assemblies with the ones you linked to solved my problem. Thanks man!